# How to manipulating STR?

Tags: python, error-handling

I start to learn Python.
Please give a review to my program:

```
i = input("input weight = ")

def chicken(i):
    price = 2000
    print('price /kg = ',price)
    totalprice = int(i)*price
    print('total price = ',totalprice)
chicken(i)
```

This program is run well if I input with number, but get an error with alphabet.

What should I do if I give an alphabet then I can do `print("wrong character")`?

Comment: `(integer/float/deciaml)(*,/,+,-)(integer/float/deciaml)` brother brother, `(integer/float/deciaml)(*,/,+,-)(str, list)` no brother

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward problem

```
i = input("input weight = ")

def chicken(i):
    price = 2000
    print('price /kg = ',price)
    totalprice = int(i)*price
    print('total price = ',totalprice)

if i.isnumeric():
    chicken(i)
else:
    print("wrong character")
```

Output:

```
input weight = a
wrong character

input weight = 5
price /kg =  2000
total price =  10000
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

The `isnumeric()` method returns True if all the characters are numeric (0-9), otherwise False.

```py
i = input("input weight = ")

def chicken(i):
      if not i.isnumeric():
        print("input is not a number")
        return 1
      price = 2000
      print('price /kg = ',price)
      totalprice = int(i)*price
      print('total price = ',totalprice)
chicken(i)
```